# Filesystem mkdir Failed to create "/client/" symfony

Tags: php, symfony, mkdir

Bonjour,

I am using the mkdir function of Filesystem bundle.
I need to create a folder for each client
I add a 777 permission for all symfony folders

```
chmod -R 777 /symfony/path/
```

But I thrown this exception with "/client/" and "/client"

Have I missed something?

My controller is easy

```
private function addFolder () {
    $fs = new Filesystem();
    $fs->mkdir('/client/');
    return;
}
```

It's running on MACOSX

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to create `client` directory in **root** folder - you should not be using `/` at the beginning of path since this means that your path specification starts at **root**.

Just replace `/client/` with `client/` and you should be good

Comment: You save my life :)